# Website acts like it has a <base> tag, but doesn't have one

Tags: php, html, radix, prepend

I am looking for debugging ideas, not sure what is happening.  All *direct* links, without the URI scheme (e.g., `http://`) don't work in an anchor.  So assuming I am working on my localhost in the directory `./includes/`:

`<a href="www.example.com">Example<a>` takes you to `127.0.0.1/includes/www.example.com`

Whereas

`<a href="http://www.example.com">Example<a>` takes you to `www.example.com`

Using a file in a different directory also fails:

`<a href="www.example.com">Example<a>` takes you to `127.0.0.1/other/directory/www.example.com` when starting in `127.0.0.1/other/directory`

This is a basic HTML coded page. It is built with PHP, and has several links to `.css` files and `.js` files.

I have confirmed:

- there isn't a `<base>` tag anywhere in the project files (netbeans project search)
- No .htaccess files anywhere
- No mod-rewrites going on anywhere.
- This is a project on my localhost (127.0.0.1). However, other projects do not have the same issue.
- When uploaded to the live server, I don't have the same problem.

In the Chrome debugger, the URI looks correct, but when I click on a link (such as www.example.com), it prepends the page information to that link, causing it to fail.  Curiously, even when *viewing source* with CTRL-U, when I click on the link it takes me to the same incorrect URI!

This is true for firefox (and firebug) as well.

Any ideas on what is causing the bad link?

Comment: I don't see what the problem is.  It is doing exactly what it should.  `http://` is for full links and without it is for a certain sub-directory or other page of the domain.

Comment: your example is not a valid achor, with out the schema local is assumed

Comment: I'm very curious to hear from the close voter how "This question was caused by **a problem that can no longer be reproduced** or **a simple typographical error**."

Comment: not me but is failure to type `http://`  a simple typographical error ?

Comment: @Dagon: Not really. That would be, e.g. `http//` instead of `http://` (missing colon) or something else that is easily missed. In this question the asker is completely aware of the missing `http://`, and the entire premise of the question revolves around it, so it's probably not just a typo. Plus I'm sure the answer to this question *will* help future readers.

Comment: I just noticed in the question "When uploaded to the live server, I don't have the same problem." Are you saying that clicking on a link without the scheme has all browsers take you to `http://www.example.com` prefilling the scheme for you, when uploaded to the live server? I would be surprised if it did.

Comment: well the changes made to the closed vote system recently just made things worse for all

Comment: @BoltClock, yes the live site DOES take me to the correct location, whereas the localhost does not.  Tested in FF and Chrome.

Comment: `<a href="www.example.com">Example<a>` tested on multiple servers and browsers, none take me to `http://www.example.com` i don't believe you are correct, are you sure nothing is adding the http:// before upload?

Comment: @SableFoste Out of curiosity, would it be possible for you to provide a link to a page on your live site that does this?

Comment: @Samutz, sure, visit www.keppiehed.com, click on the publications link.  I added a test publication.  Click on the "more info".  I added the link to `www.google.com`, not `http://www.google.com/`, and it works in my browser.  (Note, I will have to take it down later).

Comment: `<a href='http://www.google.com' title='www.google.com'>more info</a>` ???

Comment: @SableFoste When I view the source, it shows `<a href='http://www.google.com' title='www.google.com'>more info</a>` in 2 different browsers

Comment: your confusing the title with the href?

Comment: Ha! I found out what was going on... I added some code to check if the URI Scheme was included (and if it wasn't, the code added it).  I just had different versions running on the live server versus the development server.  To many re-uploads!  Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: "and if it wasn't, the code added it" so you knew all along it needed to be :-)

Comment: Exactly.  Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `href` attribute value is incorrect:

```
<a href="www.example.com">Example<a>
```

You're missing the protocol.  Put `http://` on the front:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com">Example<a>
```

Without it, how is the browser to know you didn't intend a file relative to the current one, named `www.example.com`?  You must include the protocol.

Comment: Maybe it does this because the browser always corrects it, but not on the localhost.  But are you saying that the without the URI Scheme (even on the live site) this is incorrect?  Can you point me to the documentation?

Comment: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt and http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html  and a little logic `www.example.com` is a valid file name, you could have a file called that on your server

Comment: Technically, the link is ALWAYS incorrect without `http://`, but browsers have added this feature automatically in order for a more user-friendly experience.

Comment: It is only an incorrect link if you intend it to go to that domain. If you had a file named `www.example.com` it would be perfectly valid.

Comment: @SableFoste No need to add anything... Dagon and Collin hit the nails on heads here.

Comment: @Anonymous: Seriously? That's insane. So what happens if the author did intend for the link to point to a domain-relative location, are they forced to specify an absolute URI? And why does it only work for live servers and not localhost?

Comment: @Anonymous Clarifying your comment for others...  The browser's UI adds `http://` if it's missing to URLs entered into the address bar.  There is nothing to correct in the body of a document, since it could be an actual relative reference.

Comment: @BoltClock He's talking about the address bar.

Comment: Okay, I will look a little more carefully at the documentation.  I don't see anything saying it is NOT okay to leave the URI Scheme out.  But it seems the most experienced programmers just understand it.

Comment: @Brad: Oh. I thought he was referring to the behavior specified in the question re: the links actually working as intended when the file is uploaded to a live server.

Comment: @SableFoste Think about it... you can have a real resource at `http://www.example.com/www.google.com`.  If you don't specify, that's what the browser is supposed to assume.

Comment: Okay, good discussion.  You learn something new everyday!  ;)

Comment: @BoltClock Yea, I was referring to manually visiting a link in the browser.  Sorry for any confusion.